# C# Application Lync Function migrated to MS teams

Tags: c#, sdk, microsoft-teams, lync

In our firm we have a simple WinForm C# application right now using ***Microsoft Lync 2013 SDK*** to show the persenceIndicator. For now, our firm is start to give away from Lync to Microsoft Teams, does anyone know how to code something as the below part by using some SDK like for MS teams?

Really Appreciated, if someone could help me here.

[current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8p4f.png)

Comment: Questions needs to be more concrete. You need to ask questions regarding an specific error/attempt or approach and the code should be posted in text, not with images or links to images. Keyboar shortcut ctrl + k format the text to code format for you in the questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need to use Teams for this - you can access the Graph API which has a method you can use. Note that it's beta for now though, but check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/presence-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: glad to help! Please mark as answer and upvote, so others can see this was useful if they have a similar query in future.